# How can I produce a beep in an embedded system with C?

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller

I'm kinda new here. I am trying to program a microcontroller with C to make it produce beep sound through an external speaker. I can not use standard libraries of C, so that means no beep() and I don't want to (or  can't) use '\a' because I need to be able to determine frequency and duration of beep. I couldn't find any piece of algorithms or info about beep() functions algorithm also. Thank you.

Comment: Libraries? What libraries? You need to write very low-level code that flips an external pin between 0 and 1 at the desired frequency for the duration of your beep. The exact code is entirely specific to your microcontroller, so you need to figure out a way to switch a pin from 1 to 0 and back, to measure a time interval, and to set up a way to do something at a fixed period of time (interrupt service routines).

Comment: `beep()` is not a standard library function, and '\a' would only beep if you happened to send it to a device that was capable of interpreting it as a beep.  You'd need to implement a device driver specific to your hardware.  There's a huge gap between what you have told us and what we'd need to know to answer.  We'd need to know how the speaker was physically attached to the processor and what processor it was.

Answer (score 3):

There are two fundamentally different ways of doing this, depending (in part) on what hardware is available on the microcontroller you're using.

Some microcontrollers have some sort of programmable clock/oscillator with an output pin to allow connection the outside world. If you have that, you probably want to use it. You'll basically program it for the frequency you want, turn it on, and when the beep duration is over you'll turn it back off. For the latter, you'll typically program a second timer to interrupt the processor when the duration has elapsed, or else at some set interval like 1 ms, so you can just count milliseconds until the proper duration has been reached. Details vary with the details of the hardware on your particular microcontroller.

The second choice is to do the toggling with the microprocessor itself (aka "bit banging"). You set some output line high, then wait for half a cycle of the frequency you want to generate, and set it low again. Again, by preference you set that time period with some sort of clock that will generate an interrupt at the right time. If you don't have that, you *can* set the processor in a spin loop for a specified number of cycles -- but be aware that this uses a fair amount of extra power, so (for one example) it can significantly reduce battery life if you're programming a battery powered device.

Also note that in both cases, these are producing a square wave as the output. If you want something closer to (for example) a sine wave, you'll need some extra circuitry to filter the output. With some minimal filtering, you may be able to simulate more complex wave forms with some PWM -- but that can get substantially more complex than just generating a beep of a specified frequency and duration.